# ASP.NET MVC "Convert to Web Application" option is missing in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I'm working with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and ASP.NET MVC v1. When right clicking on a view I do not get the option "Convert to Web Application" that I would need to generate code behind .cs classes. I see that option for the actual project and folders, but not for views (aspx files). I've checked the ProjectTypeGuids to have the "right" (?) values:

{603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}

Any other suggestions as to what I could look for?

Thanks.

(I am aware of design implications of using code behind classes with MVC)

P.S. To do it manually all you have to do is:

1. Add a file with the same name as your view and the .cs (or .vb) extension, for example Index.aspx.cs. Make sure you modify your class to inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage or some other class that inherits from that.
2. Edit the aspx file and add to the @Page directive CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" and change Inherits to "MyNamespace.Views.Home.Index" (obviously you need to have the right code behind and namespace there).
3. Right click on the aspx file and choose Convert to Web Application. This will create the design file and also modify your .cs class and mark it as "partial".

Comment: Are looking for 'a' way to achive this or are you after 'tooling' only?

Comment: @Maxwell: I'm looking for a way to "fix" Visual Studio to have that feature back. I could build the files by hand, but that's a lot of work, imo. Thanks.

Comment: Could somebody explain why the negative vote on this post? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why the question was downvoted. The OP is aware of the potential problems of what he wants to achieve; and it's a legit and concrete question.

Comment: @Franci Penov: The OP downvoted all of the answers that told him you can't (or shouldn't) do that with ASP.NET MVC. They're right, you shouldn't. You can mix webforms and ASP.NET MVC; but you can't bend MVC to become webforms.

Comment: 1. I don't see how downvoting the question is related to the answers being downvoted. There's a simple rule - downvoting is for providing feedback on the content, not for personal retaliation. 2. You can have code behind with MVC and that does _not_ imply WebForms necessarily. 3. Whether it's a good idea or not to have code behind is debatable; but in any case, that's not what the question is about. 4. I downvoted the two answers as they were (and still are) not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Franci: Simply because the question contains a parenthetical remark at the end to the effect of "I know that this gun is pointed at my foot, I want to shoot it anyway" does not invalidate responses of "don't shoot it" or make them irrelevant.

Comment: @Aaronaught actually, yes it does. 1. Code behind is not as nearly as dangerous, as people make it sound. Clearly not as pointing a gun to somebody's foot. :-) 2. If the OP is aware of the implications of his actions (as he pointed) and all he asked was _how_ to do it, telling him not to do it is irrelevant as an answer. SO offers comments for the purpose of making remarks that are not a direct answer to the question.

Comment: @Franci: Who decides what level of "danger" is appropriate?  The answers were both relevant and correct; disagreement on a subjective point does not IMO warrant down-voting (and not leaving any feedback with said down-votes makes it twice as rude).

Comment: @George Stocker and @Aaronaught: I have not downvoted any of the answers in this post. I appreciate the time someone takes to answer a question, and for this reason I commented on each post trying to explain my point.

Comment: @Aaronaught yes, I agree, I should've noted in the answers comments why I downvoted them.

Comment: @Aaronaught the answers were neither relevant, nor correct. MVC does not preclude code behind. It is possible to have "smart" view with code behind that contains logic that is not related to the business logic the controller is interested in. As an example, I have a smart view that switches its master page based on the area the view is invoked from. This is not a business logic and is not responsibility of the Controller. And writing a full blown view engine replacement is overkill.

Comment: @Franci: I'm curious why you claim it's not the Controller's responsibility.  The `View(...)` actually has an overload that sets the master page.  Presumably each area will have its own controller so this would be a simple way to dynamically change the master page.  You can also inherit from `WebFormViewEngine` as opposed to writing your own from scratch; I guess I'm more comfortable with this type of tinkering since I switched to Spark a while ago.  I see your point but I think that's a very specific requirement and would probably still choose a different method myself.

Comment: @Aaronaught: the areas denote different presentation layers (FB canvas vs. regular web vs. iPhone), and there are some specific controllers, but most controllers are the same between the areas, as the business logic does not change. The views itself also don't change, the presentation-layer specific initialization and rendering is covered mostly in the master and the corresponding CSS and JS files it brings.

Btw, I am still cleaning up the whole approach, and there are certain limitations of MVC 2 that makes it not as straight-forward as I'd like it to be. :-)

Comment: @Franci: I suppose I'm just asking out of curiosity now, have you considered inheriting your views from a custom `ViewPage` class and putting your master-page logic in there?  Would that not be less work than creating all those code-behind files?

Comment: @Aaronaught : but then I have to have two base classes - one for the generic version and one regular. I am still thinking about the best approach. might not use code behind after all, but not because there's anything inherently wrong with it. :-)

Comment: @Franci: True enough, though I think I'd prefer 2 base classes over 20 code-behind files. :P  I think it's also fairly straightforward to create a generic ViewPage that inherits from the non-generic with only a few extra LOC - there was an SO question on that a while back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Convert to web application" is a project/file-level command. You can't use it on a single `ASPX` file.

Also, there is no alternative automated way (that I know of :-)) to add code-behind files to an ASPX file. You have to do it manually, by adding the relevant files yourself and then adding them to the .csproj.

Comment: I've used this before with MVC, even ScottGu mentioned that in one of his replies here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx#5441681

'Just select your file in the solution explorer, right click, and choose the "Convert to Web Application" context menu option.  This will generate the .designer file for you.'

Either the MVC templates changed to where this is no longer possible or my installation is corrupt (I actually did reinstall VS just to be sure). 

Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Now that I think about it, that may have been with one of the RCs and not with the final version (1.0), though I can't remember exactly. Could it be that they removed the creation of .cs files in the MVC templates and since there's no .cs file there's no "Convert to Web Application" option (which would only generate the .designer.cs file)? For some reason I remember being able to right click on an aspx file, choose that option and VS would generate the two files for me; maybe I remember it wrong...

Comment: Yes, that was in Preview 5 of Version 1. It's changed drastically since then. :-)

Comment: @George: So the "official story" is that you can't do that (unless you do it by hand)? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to use 'code-behind' with ASP.NET MVC.

If you use a 'code-behind', you're not following the convention of ASP.NET MVC.

The question is, why do you want a code-behind? Answering that will help us to determine what you really need.

If you really want to do this, you can do it by mixing Webforms and ASP.NET MVC together. There are lots of resources on this, but [here's just one](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc).

Comment: I'm looking into avoiding peppering my views with view-related code. For example, some controls are designed to use events that require functions for processing. I do not want all that stuff to be mixed with the actual HTML. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be using ASP.NET server controls with ASP.NET MVC since they couple the controller and view.  Why use ASP.NET MVC if you aren't going to conform to its strengths?

Comment: Because there are a number of controls that I would like to reuse, rather than rebuild them in the MVC way. These particular controls do not couple with the controller in any way.

Answer (score 4):

The MVC development model does not need code behind.

Read a good Blog Post on this [Here](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/codebehind-files-in-asp-net-mvc-are-evil/)

Comment: Like I mentioned in the last sentence I'm aware of these design implications (i.e. debate). This post is not about rehashing those arguments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to reuse some controls, maybe a good approach is to create and render them inside a helper method and than call that method from the view.

What I'm thinking about would be something like this:

```
public static string HelperMethod(param_list)
{
   var control = new ControlType();
   //set up control properties according to param_list

   //get the html as string - one way to do it would be like this
   StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
   HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter= new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
   control.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
   string result= stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

And then call it from the view like this:

```
<%= HelperClass.HelperMethod(params) %>
```

I'm not sure if this approach will work, I don't know even if it makes sense. It's more of I hack than a proper solution. I haven't done anything like this before, it's just an idea, try to see if it helps you. You should also have in mind that ASP.NET controls usually use the ViewState for state management and that there is no such thing in ASP.NET MVC.