# Converting C# MVC-4 View to Web-Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

So i got a small aspx View on a running MVC-4 / Ext.Net 2.1 application. i want to covert it to a "Web-Application" with code-behind and designer.

When first clicking "Convert to web-application" in the context menu of the View i got following Error message:

```
Unable to convert to Web Application because Code-Behind file is missing
```

after creating a new class named "Default.aspx.cs" and referencing it from "Default.aspx" as Code-Behind file i got the following Error message:

```
Class 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>' not found in code-behind file
```

i tried directly using 'System.Web.Mvc' as well as creating a class and initializing an instance of it in :

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ViewPage<dynamic> viewpage = new ViewPage<dynamic>();
   //Do Some Stuff
}
```

now i am asking SO for help, as googling didn't bring forth results other than 'ext.net/download' or 'msdn.microsoft.com/asp.net/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASP.NET MVC "Convert to Web Application" option is missing in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215277/asp-net-mvc-convert-to-web-application-option-is-missing-in-visual-studio) answered this question quite well. after following the steps described, the conversion worked.

the code Behind now looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Ext.Net;
using Ext.Net.MVC;
using Ext.Net.Utilities;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyNamespace.Views.Component
{
    public partial class Default : ViewPage<dynamic>
    {
    //do the usual stuff
    }
}
```

and the Default.aspx's @Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Base.Master"
CodeBehind="~/Views/Component/Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.Views.Component.Default" AutoEventWireup="True" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>
```